# Comparing two values from two separate matrices in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, matrix

I am using transact SQL and SSRS to build a report. I have to compare two completely separate date parameters on the same dataset. One date parameter is the last 12 months and the other is the last fiscal year.

I need to compare the results obtained from each set. The dataset is extensive and so I figured the best method would be to create two matrices with the same dataset except that the date parameters are different. I am grouping by geographic areas on my rows and I need to return an arithmetic comparison between the present year and fiscal year on the row groups.

Can a person compare numbers on a row group between two separate matrices in SSRS?

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference other report objects (like matrices) in expressions, so what you're thinking of doing probably won't work.  You can, however, use Lookup() and LookupSet() (requires SSRS 2008 R2 or newer), to pull fields out of other (or the same) *dataset*.